# Match characters at end of string

Tags: regex

```
xxxTxxx
```

or

```
xxxTxx
```

or

```
xxxTx
```

I want to get **all** x's at the end.

`(.*)(x$)` will only get me the last x.
`(.*)(x*$)` won't work, because it don't match the end. I need to use some look behind magic, right?

Thanks you regex heads!

Comment: I'm assuming the "T" is a placeholder and isn't guaranteed to be there, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
^(.*?)(x+)$
```

You'll have the x in group 2 and all that is before in group 1.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the `x`s at the end, you can use:

```
/(x+)$/
```

This basically says to look at the end of the string for at least one x and find as many as possible.

If you want all `x`s at the beginning, you can use:

```
/^(x+)/
```

This does the same thing but tells it to look at the beginning of the string.

Comment: What if I also want everything before the x'es?

Comment: I'll add that.  One moment.

Answer (score 1):

Will it always be a 'T'?

In which case:

```
 T(x*)$
```

Or perhaps the T could be anything except 'x':

```
 [^x](x*)$
```

Edit:

Actually:

```
(x*)$
```

... is sufficent. It will greedily consume 'x's. If at the end of a run of 'x's it finds end end of the string, that's a match. Otherwise it discards them and starts trying to match again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this pattern:

using RegexOptions.RightToLeft you will be sure that you start looking for the end of the string.

```
string text = "xxxTxxx";
string pattern = @"x+";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
string temp = r.Match(text).Value;
```

The output will be:

"xxx"

And if you want to be sure that is at the end of the text, use this:

```
string text = "xxxTxxx&";
string pattern = @"x+$";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
string temp = r.Match(text).Value;
```

In this case the output will be:

""

Comment: How do you know he's using .NET?  As far as I know, that's the only regex flavor that offers a right-to-left matching option.

Comment: Hi Alan! And yes, you are right, I don´t know! But how he doesn´t specify the language, I put the answer in the language I know ;) Maybe could be useful for him if he is using .NET, if not.. then it wont!